# Box Shadow Cutting Off at page cut off

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

I'm having some troubke with the box shadow property on my page.

The shadow seems to cut off at the point where the page exceeds the screen size, and i'm not sure why.

I'm simply trying to achieve a lighting effect using pure css rather than heavy png's. I've used an inset shadow to achieve what i have, and applied it to the body, and it looks great, but the cut off is killing it on smaller screens.

If somebody could give me a hand fixing or an alternative that'd be great.

http://mock.koansystems.co.uk

```
html {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
}

body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: #000006;
        background-image: url(/img/repeat11.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        box-shadow  : inset 0px 0px 200px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put your style here...anyway when I turn your body height into "auto" instead of "100%" using inspect element, the shadow contains all the body. change body height into "auto" and see the result.

Comment: Tried it, but that's even worse, haha!

Comment: It may be affected by other styles...if you can post the html & css code, it'll be a great help to solve your problem.

Comment: added css to the post